# Caesar Cipher encryption/decryption

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

This program takes a command line argument of how many times you would like to encrypt plain text. After you compile the program, input a message you would like to have coded.  I'm new to C and curious about how to make this program more efficient.

```
/*
*caesar.c
*
*
*
*Encrypts user supplied messages according to a user supplied   encryption key 
*
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

  if (argc != '\0' && argc == 2 )   
  { 

    //converting string input to integers
    int f= atoi(argv[1]);


    //getting string command from user
    string a = GetString();

    for(int i = 0, j = strlen(a); i < j; i++)
    {

        if ( isalpha (a[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(a[i]))
            {
                //converting capitalized chars
                char acap = (a[i] - 65);
                int ccap = (acap+f)%26;
                //final capitalized chars loop
                char ecap = ccap + 65;
                printf("%c", ecap);
            }

            else if (islower(a[i]))
            {
                //converting small chars
                char asma = (a[i] - 97);
                int csma = (asma+f)%26;
                //final small chars loop
                char esma = csma + 97;
                printf("%c", esma);
            }

       }
       else
       {
           printf("%c", a[i]);
       }

    }            printf("%c", esma);
    return 0;
}   
else   
{
    return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post `cs50.h`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unnecessarily complicated:

> ```
>   if (argc != '\0' && argc == 2 )
> ```

This is exactly the same thing but simpler:

```
  if (argc == 2)
```

---

Instead of the hard-coded ASCII code 65 of "A", you could use `'A'` to make the code easier to read. So instead of this:

> ```
> //converting capitalized chars
> char acap = (a[i] - 65);
> int ccap = (acap+f)%26;
> //final capitalized chars loop
> char ecap = ccap + 65;
> printf("%c", ecap);
> ```

You can write like this:

```
//converting capitalized chars
char acap = (a[i] - 'A');
int ccap = (acap + f) % 26;
//final capitalized chars loop
char ecap = ccap + 'A';
printf("%c", ecap);
```

I also added spaces around operators in `(acap+f)%26` to make it more readable, which is a good practice.

The same goes for the number 97, it's better to use `'a'` instead.

---

The code for handling upper case and lower case letters is practically the same, except for the constant `'A'` and `'a'`.
Avoid such code duplication, repetition and copy-paste coding as much as possible.
Extract the common logic to a helper function,
and reuse it by passing `'A'` and `'a'` as parameter.

---

Use more descriptive variable names.
`f`, `acap`, `ccap`, `ecap` are really not intuitive,
and your code could become much more readable if you gave these better names.

---

[@Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39848/edward) made an excellent remark in comments that I'm just going to quote verbatim:

> It's worth noting that both original and suggested changes assume a
>   character encoding with a contiguous encoding for the alphabet. This
>   is not actually guaranteed by the C standard. For example, EBCDIC
>   systems are admittedly rare but not yet extinct.

Comment: It's worth noting that both original and suggested changes assume a character encoding with a contiguous encoding for the alphabet.  This is not actually guaranteed by the C standard.  For example, EBCDIC systems are admittedly rare but not yet extinct.

Comment: Thanks @Edward, that's an excellent point. I added to my post.

Comment: Thanks guys, really helpful.  @ janos, is it usually recommended to then use 'A'/ 'a' instead of their numerical values (as long as it was consistent throughout the code)?

Comment: @JordanV absolutely! The readability benefit is crystal clear, and the code will compile to the exact same binary.

Answer (score 4):

### Get your types right

> ```
> int main(int argc, string argv[])
> ```

I'm not aware of any C compiler that has a `string` type. I assume that this is a `typedef` or `#define` inside `"cs50.h"`. It's a really bad idea, as it will make your code difficult to port to C++ if you ever choose to do so. In C, strings are not real types; arrays (or buffers) of `char` stand in for them. A quoted string is just a shortcut for creating a buffer; the string operation functions actually operate on buffers.

### Separate user interface and business logic

Your `main` routine should handle input and output, but not any real logic. The actual logic of your program should be in a separate function. `main` should call that function.

### Use simplest available function

> ```
> printf("%c", a[i]);
> ```

`putchar()` would be a better choice for outputting a single `char`. But you really ought to be creating/modifying a buffer of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

**compilation Error**

I encountered a compilation error for your code on the ideone c compiler.

> prog.c:2:18: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
>    #include

In pure C declaring  a string using string method is not entertained it is more of a c++ method.